# C++17 pointer to tempalte class with class template default argument

Tags: templates, c++17, default-template-argument

I am experimenting with C++17 class template default argument and was wondering if anyone could explain:

If I have the following:

```
template<typename Policy = DefaultPolicy>
class MyClass { //class goes here };
```

And then try to use it as:

```
MyClass * class = new MyClass();
```

I get the error:

However both the following compile OK:

```
MyClass stackClass = MyClass();

auto * heapClass = new MyClass();
```

In particular I am very interested in how auto is working above. Thanks so much!

Perhaps there is also a concept name that describes this that I can google for more info also.

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/EbEnxjcej

Comment: not related to your issue: `MyClass * class = new MyClass();` This is very bad. Don't use manual memory management in C++ (`new`, `delete`). Use smart pointers.

Comment: Yes, a similar issues occurs. I was hoping an explanation would explain this also: https://godbolt.org/z/KcP1xjahq

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax forming a pointer to a template  instance with default parameter would be:

```
MyClass<> * heapClass = new MyClass();  
auto smartClass = std::make_unique<MyClass<>>(); // for same reason
```

`MyClass` formally isn't a type-id, it's a template name. That's why `make_unique` would fail, because its parameter should be a `typename`. Pointer declaration syntax would require same. What `auto` does is use of a full type-id - `MyClass<DefaultPolicy>`.
The new expression is one of  special cases allowed in C++17 along with `MyClass stackClass` although for clarity `new MyClass<>()` can be used as pre-17.

Comment: Thank you! This explains it really well. I guess this is a short coming of template based policy design, it isn't very friendly in the user code.

Comment: @MarcusRaty it's inescapable, afaik. There are context where a template name can be used and it should be distinguished from type name. It's possible to have `template <template<class> class T> class MyTempl {};`, in that case `MyTemp<MyClass>()` is legal as is different from  `MyTemp<MyClass<>>()`  which must be `template<class T>`.